# How to unit test the LINQ queries in Cosmos DB using XUnit

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb, xunit

```
    public async Task<List<Group>?> GetInfosforGroupIdAsync(string groupId)
    {
           Container? cosmosContainer =
           await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("Group", "/GroupId");
           if (groupId == null)
              return null;
                
           var query = cosmosContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<Group>()
                    .Where(d => d.GroupId == groupId);
           var queryResult = query.ToFeedIterator();
           if (queryResult.HasMoreResults)
           {
               FeedResponse<Group> currentResultSet = await queryResult.ReadNextAsync();
               List<DedupeGroup> result = currentResultSet.ToList<Group>();
               return result;
           }
           return null;
   }
```

How can I write units tests for the above method using `xunit` tests.
Assume `Group` is like below

```
class Group{
  string GroupId;
  string GroupInfo;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest just to create test database and do functional testing on that database. No moks, just prepared data for testing.

Comment: I have done that but it is compulsory to write unit tests :(

Comment: @rakhi Says who?

Comment: What are you trying to test here?

Comment: @MoB. I will push some data to MockDatabase and retrieve it and verify the data which is coming out of Database.

Comment: Not all classes can be mocked. Hence, we use Ignore attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute?view=mstest-net-1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

That's generally not a good idea. If you really wanted to unit test the method as shown, you would need to create mockups of all the used Cosmos DB classes. This would be a lot of code for little value in return (or even negative net value since tests have to be maintained, may contain bugs etc.). But that's not the biggest problem.

You could factor out the thing that you actually want to unit test and only test that, namely the LINQ expression. You could test the `IQueryable` by mocking it with a normal in-memory `IEnumerable`. But that doesn't actually work in general because LINQ queries on an `IEnumerable` don't behave like LINQ queries against Cosmos DB. For example, the null-coalesce operator in C# (`??`) is translated into an undefined-coalesce operator in Cosmos DB (`??`), or you can access non-existing keys using an indexer in Cosmos DB without error (`c['foo']`) but you get a `KeyNotFoundException` in-memory.

Unfortunately, there is no in-memory mock `CosmosClient` avaiable at the moment. So you would have to write your own LINQ provider that interprets LINQ queries *exactly* like Cosmos DB does, but in-memory, which would be a *lot* of work for very little value in return.